# Alterando dados no Banco de dados usando Checkbox

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, wordpress, checkbox, sql-update

Olá, tenho uma tabela que exibe dados de um banco, e ela contém checkbox. Quero selecionar um checkbox dessas linhas da tabela, e quando clicar no botao inativar ele vai inserir o valor 0 numa linha do banco.
Tabela:

```
    <thead>

      <tr style="border:2px solid #373737; color:white; background-color:#434343;">
        <th>Selecionar</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>CPF</th>
        <th>CNPJ</th>
        <th>Cidade</th>
        <th>Rua</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
foreach($resultado as $key => $valor):
?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" name = "<?php $nomeDaEmpresa = $valor->nome;?>"/></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->nome;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->cpf;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->cnpj;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->cidade;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $valor->rua;?></td>
        <td><?php 
        if($valor -> status == 1){

          echo "Ativa";
            

        }

        else{

            echo "Desativada";

        }
        ?></td>
      </tr>
      
<?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Query:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$resultado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT nome, cpf, cnpj, cidade, rua, status FROM wp_tblempresa WHERE admin = '$userlogin'");
?>
```

Botao:

```
   <form method = "POST" action = "" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
            <input type="submit" style="background-color:#009ada; color:white; " name="inativar" 
            class="btn margin col-lg-2 m-1" value="Inativar">
    </form>
```

PHP:

````
global $wpdb;

$tabela_nome = $wpdb->prefix . 'tblempresa';

        if(!empty ($_POST['inativar'])){
       
        $update = $wpdb->query("UPDATE `wp_tblempresa` SET status = 0 WHERE nome = 
        '$nomeDaEmpresa';");
      
         }
    
?> ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duas soluções:

### Redirecionando

Você pode redirecionar o `submit` para o arquivo de `action`. Ele seria um script php que vai rodar a query de `update` no banco de dados e depois redirecionar de volta pra a devida página que o usuário deve ir.

Primeiro adicione o caminho pro script no atributo `action` do formulário:

```
<form action="your-php-script.php">
```

Depois adicione um redirect no final do script php:

```
    global $wpdb;

    $tabela_nome = $wpdb->prefix . 'tblempresa';

    if(!empty ($_POST['inativar'])){
      $update = $wpdb->query("UPDATE ...");
    }

    // depois de ter rodado o update

    header("Location: https://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
    die();
```

### Requisição dinâmica

Você também pode criar um handler javascript pra o clique no botão, mas isso precisaria de conhecimento em js. Essa solução é interessante pq não fica redirecionando o usuário pra lá e pra cá, ela lida de forma assíncrona e dinâmica na própria página. Você pode usar a [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) pra fazer a requisição. O `js` seria algo assim:

```
// encontrar o botão pelo id
document.getElementById('submit-button')
   // criar uma handler que é chamado sempre que o botão é clicado
  .addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // impedir o comportamento padrão do submit atualizar a página
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // fazer a requisição do script php
    fetch('your-php-script.php')
      // converter a resposta 
      .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
          // aqui você sabe que tudo deu certo
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
         // aqui você sabe que algo deu errado na requisição
      })

  })
```

Além disso, é válido responder à requisição - no script php - com um status code como o [204](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204), que significa que:

> A requisição foi bem sucedida e o cliente não precisa sair da página atual.

```
// ... depois de ter executado a query no banco
http_response_code(204); 
die();
```